# Optimizing $F(x)+F(1-x)$ where $F$ is a CDF

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization

Lets say you are trying to optimize the function $g(x) = F(x) +F(1-x)$ where $F$ is the CDF for some distribution bounded between $0$ and $1$. We take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ and we get $g'(x)= f(x)-f(1-x)$ so the function has local maximums/minimums where $f(x) = f(1-x)$ and has end points at $0$ and $1$, so trivial potential maximums at $0$, $0.5$ and $1$ and then wherever else $f(x) = f(1-x)$.

Now consider the distribution that satisfies $F(0.1) = 0.4$, $F(0.5) = 0.4+\epsilon$, $F(0.6) = 0.75$ and $f(x)$ does not equal $f(1-x)$ for any $x$.  So by the logic above this function should have a max at 0, 0.5 or 1. Easy to see that these give $g(0) =1$,$g(0.5) =0.8+\epsilon$, $g(1) = 1$ respectively. However, plugging in $x=0.6$ gives something like $g(0.6) = 1.15$.

Have I made a mistake computing the derivative? Is such a distribution impossible to construct for some reason? Or is there an even more fundamental mistake in my reasoning here?

Comment: You haven't defined $F$ entirely; how can you guarantee that $f(x) \ne f(1-x)$ for other values of $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, your $g$

- has positive derivative somewhere in $[0.5, 0.6]$,
- has negative derivative somewhere in $[0.6, 1]$.

If your density $f$ is continuous, then $g'$ is also continuous, so there will be some $x \in (0.5, 1)$ such that $g'(x)=0$. So your claim that your CDF $F$ is such that "$f(x)$ does not equal $f(1-x)$ for any [other] $x$" cannot hold.